# Ask password while dowloading the file via handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

WHile downloading a file like this

```
<a target="_self" href="/abc/accc/Document/downloadFile.ashx?id=667491E0-6581-4AD5-A23F-4CB99F4075ED">Some file name</a>
```

it should be prompted the password field and when password is inputted, file will be downloadable....:)
I using a handler to download the file in asp.net with c#

i just brief the requirement.. actually file will be searchable across the internet... these files will be protected with a pass key. Anyone searches the file if he click the file to download it will prompted for the password like in modalpopextender having password textbox. he will conatct the file owner to request the password. On gathering the password he will be able to download the password..

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to don't link directly the file but save the id in viewstate or session and add a login page that show up on link pressed.

```
<a target="_self" href="/login.aspx?id=667491E0-6581-4AD5-A23F-4CB99F4075ED">Some file name</a>
```

then in login.aspx ask for credential and if succesfull redirect to Handler.ashx.

Comment: i brief the requirement.. actually file will be searchable across the internet... these files will be protected with a pass key. Anyone searches the file if he click the file to download it will prompted for the password like in modalpopextender having password textbox. he will conatct the file owner to request the password. On gathering the password he will be able to download the password..

Answer (score 0):

You can write an httpmodule and validate all requests to your handler.